# System.Mail.Net through Gmail but redirected to an identity portal

Tags: c#, .net, gmail

I am having an issue with sending an email through an app using Gmail. I have it working on a normal gmail account for development. Now I am moving the email over to the clients preferred email address also host by google but there is a twist with theirs that I cannot figure out. First off I have all the correct info for the address as well as enabled allow less secure apps enabled on the account. The issue  is that to log into the account I type the email address into gmail like normal. Then I am redirected to a portal for identity verification and then once logged in there with a username and password I am redirected back to google where I can view the email account. Is there a way to get this to work through Mail.Net? I get it has to do with security but I am unsure what I'll need to do to get it to execute through the portal as well.

Comment: how do you mean redirected to a portal? smtp doesnt do that sort of thing.

Comment: Thats my issue I am trying to send email from an app which works perfectly with an @ gmail account. The one that I am trying to use now is a managed gmail account so @somedomain.com. To get to the emails I go to gmail and log in. from there I am redirected to a portal for user authentication then on successful login in the portal its redirected back to gmail like gmail would normally be. Is there a way to do this authentication and still send an email using .net? I am unfamiliar with that.

Comment: I figured it out. They had a username that was different then the email. Using just the email worked instead of logging in with the shortened username. doh!